# Mongoimport - using --upsertFields to extend documents subarray (not replace)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this collection

```
/**
 * Poll Options Schema
 */
var PollOptionSchema = new Schema({
    option:{type:String},
    option_thumb:{type:Number,default:0},
    votes:[{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Vote'
    }]
});
```

I have numerous JSON files, each with the same documents (about 10000 documents) but each contains diffrent records in the votes array (dont ask why). how can I use mongoimport to extend each docuements vote array and not just replace it with another array?

Comment: You cannot do this with mongoimport at present. You'll need to write your own script to handle extending the arrays.

Comment: could you give me a few pointers on how to do it / reference me to somewhere?

Comment: I would use a csv parsing library for Node and then make Mongoose models out of it and save them to the database. Based on what I see on SO, for csv work in Node everybody uses [csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv).